# Resource scheduling problem

Tags: algorithm, schedule

I'm developing a motorcycle hire website. The problem I have is how to solve the problem of assignment a guest to a motorcycle in an efficient way. I know how to do it in a "silly" way, but I want to know if there is a classical algorithm that solves this kind of problem. It's the same problem as the assignment of a guest to rooms in a hotel. In this last example, the goal is to achive maximum occupancy by never rejecting a reservation due to inefficient scheduling.

I'm pretty sure that this problem has to be a classic problem that has a known solution.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What's wrong with the silly way? What problem does it create?

Comment: Please describe the problem itself.  What can be the obstacles to assigning a free guest to a free motorcycle?

Answer (score 1):

What you're interested in is called [Interval Scheduling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_scheduling). Assuming all reservations have the same weight (none are favored over any other), you'd want a greedy algorithm.

[Here (pdf)](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~wayne/kleinberg-tardos/04greedy-2x2.pdf) are some good slides about the topic.

Basically, you want to schedule the earliest-ending reservations first.

Answer (score 0):

This is Interval scheduling but it's an online algorithm. If you want to read further you can read here:

http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~dkempe/teaching/online.pdf