# Scheduling problem with fixed reservations to a resource

Tags: algorithm, optimization, schedule

Imagine that we have a restaurant with n tables. A customer can ask for a reservation (at any table) for some start-end time interval in the future. We can neither change the start-end interval nor break it amidst and assign it to a different resource (table), but we can choose any table we want to place the reservation before the customer arrives. **What we want is to fit as many reservations as we can** given there are limited tables. A greedy optimization algorithm (sorting by start date), can find a very quick solution to the problem, unless we introduce **customer locked tables**. Some customers prefer a specific table (because of the view, or because they just like the place) and therefore their reservation cannot be moved to another resource (which makes the resource unavailable for this time-frame). So far I've tried: Greedy optimization (cannot find a decision), a genetic algorithm (most of times finds a solution, but it's very slow when for example there are many reservations), some custom made algorithm that tries a greedy fit from fixed to fixed reservation (most of times fails)

Given all this info I have 2 questions:

1. Is there an algorithm that solves this kind or similar problems? (I've seen that Branch and Bound could solve this, but unless there is a fixed reservation in our case, we cannot remove a branch of the solution. Edit: maybe backtracking could suit this problem better?)
2. What is the space state tree for this problem? I'm using just the resource numbers (table numbers) for now. Is this correct?

I am also aware of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506825/resource-scheduling-problem). It is the same problem but without the fixed reservation requests.

Comment: Can be the case that a customer locked table is given to another customer and later on that day, that specific customer should be able to reserve his specific table?

Comment: Yes mostly. This is why the heuristic optimization algorithms fail. A locked reservation is, in practice, non sortable, or better say, its priority is infinite, hence whichever logic you follow, either inserting them first, or prioritizing them over other reservations will fail since at a point a huge non-locked one will overlap with a later locked one. This is why I think ordering may not matter in this problem, but I'm still not sure.

Comment: Then maybe just forget in the main algorithm about these VIP tables and think about a rule of availability for them to be introduced in the total number of tables. I think is better if you can add some condition or restrict a bit these VIP tables, otherwise, those will be just dedicated to some customers and cannot be used for anything else. Maybe, yes, you can make a prediction algorithm based on those known customers to maximize their table usage but this will be very specific to your business case.

Comment: Yes, I know, but business is strict to this, they cannot accept a solution which only allows some locked reservations to come in. They need every VIP in, even if that ruins an optimal solution, which could potentially bring more income. It's their policy. Forecasting *could* be interesting, but it's a bit off of what I'd call "finding an optimal solution", again, I'm tied to business logic and needs.

Comment: Also having in mind a real case scenario, I am thinking of using all the tables in greedy mode and if a customer of a VIP tables makes a reservation, somehow cancel other reservation(s) which is/are for that table and announce the people, but before doing that maybe you can try checking if you have a suitable table to make an exchange and immediately switch their reservation.

Comment: Oh, I probably gave some poor explanation regarding the locked ones. If all tables are reserved for a time-frame and someone comes to lock one in this time-frame (even it they are VIP) they will not get a reservation. They'll be offered a different time-frame, for that specific table. What I've meant before, is that, if an algorithm "decides" (based on some weight) that a locked one should be thrown out to get a better fitness, it's impossible. Reservations are given only when time is available, and to know if time is available, we must first optimize the reservations

Comment: This means we are getting back to the interval schedule algorithm like you already mentioned, but for every customer take as a first option their preferred table if available if not, gave another free one. But I am still feeling like I cannot get on your page with your business case and I am sorry about that. I hope that having this conversation here will help others to come up with an idea or helping you trying another perspective for your problem.

Comment: What about using a real optimization model (e.g. a MIP model)? Fixing assignments is then no problem.